# Invoke intranet site in azure Trigger/function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We are trying to migrate an intranet site to azure scheduled job (like Trigger or function etc).
Basically this intranet site pulls record(data) in desired format.

As expected when i tried to Invoke the site in azure function it is throwing 'unknown host error'. We came to know its possible through gateway or VNET and wanted to know if any other options than this.

Please do share your thoughts & inputs on this.

Comment: AFAIK, you could follow [Azure Relay service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it) and [Azure App Service Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).

Comment: When you write 'gateway', do you mean [Azure Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway)? Because that is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to run functions in the public cloud but have them access on-prem resources, then the main options you'll want to look at are:

- [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it#hybrid-connections)
- [Virtual Networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet)

However note that as of right now, neither of these options are available to function apps configured to run in the consumption plan.

Another possible option is to run functions on premise, using [Azure Functions Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview).